# Managing Urls while clicking on User profile

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm managing to send emails to users that are present in my table and then showing success message on the same page. I'm successfully sending email to users(taking their id and then their email to send). While creating urls, I need to mention **id** as well which redirects me to another page. But what I want is to be redirected on the same page.

Here's the table which contains the users:
[image]

After clicking Send Mail, I'm taking the userid then email with this and then sendig mail.

Taking **userid**:

```
<a href="{% url 'profiles:sendMails' id=p.id %}"></button><span class="badge badge-success">Send Mail</span></a>
```

Here's my **views.py** code on this button:

```
def sendMails(request, id=None):
    query_user = get_object_or_404(NewUser, id=id)
    user_email = query_user.user
    admin_email = request.user.email
    result = send_emails(request, admin_email, user_email)

    context = {
        'code': result
    }
    return render(request,'requested_users.html', context)
```

And **urls.py**:

```
path('dashboard/requested_users/<id>', views.sendMails, name='sendMails'),
```

What I want to be on same page even after sending mail(such that the urls will be):

```
path('dashboard/requested_users/', views.sendMails, name='sendMails'),
```

But if I'm not providing the **id** in the urls, it's giving me the error:

> Reverse for 'sendMails' with keyword arguments '{'id': 1}' not found.

I know I've asked a long question, but I'm really stuck into this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you use `path('dashboard/requested_users/', ...)` then `id` will be `None` and `query_user = get_object_or_404(NewUser, id=id)` will raise 404. If you use `id` in the view then you need to pass it to the view somehow, and using `'dashboard/requested_users/<id>'` is one of the best ways to do so.

Comment: @Alasdair But using `dashboard/requested_users/<id>` redirects me to another page which I don't want. Is there any way that just after `dashboard/requested_users/<id>`, it automatically takes me back on the same page?

Comment: Yes of course, your `sendMails` should return a redirect to the desired page, rather than rendering a template.